# What is wrong with my Chest script?

Tags: unity, javascript, unityscript

I'm making an RPG in Unity3D and I am trying to make a script for a chest to open. So I built this script! But it doesn't work. I just want some help fixing this script.

```
#pragma strict
var Text : GameObject;
var OpenedChest : GameObject;
var CurrentChest : GameObject;

function OnTriggerEnter()
{
    Text.SetActive(true);
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        CurrentChest.SetActive(false);
        OpenedChest.SetActive(true);
    }
}

function OnTriggerExit()
{
    Text.SetActive(false);
}
```

I get no compiler errors. When I go into the collider that triggers the text, that works, but what doesn't is when I press E to open the chest. It doesn't activate the other chest. What is wrong with my script?

Answer (score 6):

The issue in your code is that you only check for the key press in the `OnTriggerEnter` function, which only gets called when the collider enters the trigger. What you probably want to do instead is check for the keypress inside the [`OnTriggerStay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) function, which gets called while the collider lies inside the trigger.

Comment: Always happy to help, glad to hear that this solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Is the script attached to the game object of one of the two chests `CurrentChest` and `OpenChest`? Then keep in mind that deactivating a game object also deactivates all scripts attached to it. That means any events on them won't fire anymore. You likely only want to disable specific components of the chests.

Comment: I know that. Infact I created an empty game object and put the 2 chests in there with the game object having the script on it. Still nothing works. But someone already helped with it. Thanks anyway.